# crystal report text object merge

Tags: crystal-reports, report

---

### Desc.    |   Status  |  Date     |

a       |
   a       |    sub    | 01/01/2012|
   a       |    ack    | 02/01/2012|

### a       |    inv    | 03/01/2012|

이런식으로 데이터베이스 필드로 출력을 하는데

크리스탈 레포트에 중복되면 표시안함을 하면

---

### Desc.    |   Status  |  Date     |

a       |
           |    sub    | 01/01/2012|
           |    ack    | 02/01/2012|

### |    inv    | 03/01/2012|

### 이렇게 a가 가장위에나오도러구요 이거를 혹시 중간맞춤?을 할수있을까요?

### Desc.    |   Status  |  Date     |

```
       |
```

a       |    sub    | 01/01/2012|
           |    ack    | 02/01/2012|

### |    inv    | 03/01/2012|

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Could you update your question to provide a description of what your problem is and a bit of code might help too.

Comment: Also, StackOveflow Questions should be in English.